# Accessing an uninitialized value, most probably in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am doing an exercise where I need to find a positive integers `p` and `q` which are factors of another natural number `n`.
Following the formula `n=pq*q` where p is a *squarefree* number.

However, for some instances of the program my compiler detects a memory error saying that I am accessing an uninitialized value.

The logic I tried is as follows. Firstly, I took the number that needs to be factored (name it n). Next I found all factors of the number n and placed them in a vector. After that, check if every element of that vector is *squarefree*. If true, put the element in another vector(a vector of squarefree factors of the number n). After that, go through every element of the vector of squarefree factors and solve the equation `q=sqrt(n/p)` where p is the squarefree factor from the vector. Additionally, I check the condition `if(int(sqrt(n/p))==sqrt(n/p))` because the square root needs to be a positive integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
// Function that checks if the number is squarefree

bool isSquareFree(int n)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        n = n / 2;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            n = n / i;
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void Factorise_the_number(int n, int &p, int &q)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    vector<int> factors(0); // vector of factors
    vector<int> sqfree_factors(0); // vector of squarefree factors
    int sqfree_number; // the number "p"
    int squared; // is essentially the number "q"

    for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            factors.push_back(i); // takes all factors of the number "n"
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isSquareFree(factors.at(i)))
            sqfree_factors.push_back(factors.at(i));
    } // checks if each factor is squarefree. if yes, put it in a separate vector

    for (auto x : sqfree_factors)
    {

        if (int(sqrt(n / x)) == sqrt(n / x))
        { // if true, we found the numbers
            squared = sqrt(n / x);
            sqfree_number = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    p = sqfree_number;
    q = squared;
}

int main()
{

    int n, p = 0, q = 0;
    cin >> n;

    Factorise_the_number(n, p, q);
    cout << p << " " << q;

    return 0;
}
```

For example, my program works if I enter the number `99`, but doesn't work if I enter `39`. Can anyone give any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: `return 0;` looks odd in a function that returns `void`.

Comment: Also unrelated: instead of expressing multiple return values as reference arguments, I usually prefer to have the function return a structure with the return values.  That makes things easier on the caller: `auto pq = Factorise_the_number(n);` as opposed to `int p; int q; Factorise_the_number(n, p, q);`

Comment: Instead of `int n, p=0, q=0; cin >> n;`, use `int n=99, p=0, q=0;` Now people don't have to type in `n`. They can keep testing the same case over and over until it's cracked. Faster and less chance of wasting time accidentally debugging a typo.

Comment: @user4581301 actually try type in `10`, `9223`, `57683`. It doesn't work for them, too. I just found that out. It does work for the following: `77777, 48, 22360800`

Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: @DanielSchepler now that you mention such a possibility it is niftier, but I don't know how to return a structure yet! Thanks

Comment: If it never enters the loop because sqfree_factors is empty then it will use uninitialized values.

Comment: @user4581301 Can you suggest an alternative? I understand what using uninitialized variables means but I don't see how (or where) to fix it!

Comment: Do you need `sqfree_number`? At the end of the day it just looks like it's `p`. Why not use `p`? Better still, make `sqfree_number` the parameter and do away with `p`. The more descriptive name should always win out. Makes for easier-to-read code.

Comment: @ZanLynx Yes, but take for instance the number `123`. The sqfree_factors for it shouldn't be empty (should contain `3 and 41`) right?

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the suggestion. I changed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, for 39 it doesn't work. Have you checked what it's doing with 39? You should do it, as it is the best way to debug your program.

Let's have a look at it together. First it tries to find all the factors, and it finds 1, 3 and 13: this looks fine.

Then, it checks whether each of those numbers is squarefree, and they all are: this also looks correct.

Then, it checks whether any of the squarefree factors satisfy the equality you are looking for. None of them does (39 is 3 x 13, there's no way it can contain a squared factor). This means that `if (int(sqrt(n / x)) == sqrt(n / x))` is never true, and that block is never run. What's the value of `sqfree_number` and `squared` at that point? It is never initialised. Using uninitialised values leads to "undefined behaviour", that is, your program can do anything. In this case, `p` and `q` end up containing random values.

How can you fix it? Consider this: if `n` doesn't satisfy your equation, that is, it can't be expressed as pq*q, what, exactly, should the program output? Would your output, as it is now, ever make sense? No. This means you have to modify your program so that it covers a case you hadn't considered.

A way is to add a `bool found = false;` just before your final `for` loop. When you find the factors, before breaking, set that variable to `true`. Then, outside the loop, check it: is it `true`? Then you can return the correct values. But if it's still `false`, it means the equality doesn't hold, and you can't return correct values. You have to find a way to signal this to the caller (which is your `main` function), so that it can print an appropriate message.

And how can you signal it? In general, you could change your `Factorise_the_number` (by the way, the name of functions should start with a lowercase letter; uppercase letters are usually used for classes) to return a `bool`. Or you could use a trick: return a special value for `p` and `q` that cannot be the result of the calculation. Like -1. Then, before printing, check: if the values are -1, it means the number can't be expressed as pq*q.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I was able to solve it after you pointed me to the right direction. May I ask one more thing though, do you think that this algorithm is too inefficient? Because the exercise says that there are many ways to perform such a factoring(one of which would be via finding all prime factors of the number `n`, but that there should be many more algorithms)?

Comment: A faster approach would be to change the order of your checks from breadth-first to depth-first. Right now you find *all* the factors, then you check *all* of them for squarefree-ness, and then you try the equality for *all* of them. Imagine the factors are 1000, and 500 are squarefree. Of these, the third one satisfies the equality. It means that hundreds of checks were useless! Instead, when you find a factor, check if it is squarefree immediately, and if it is, check the equality. It's faster, and you also save memory, because there's no need to store your results.

Comment: Alternative algorithm: you just need to factor the number, and then it satisfies your equality if there's at least a factor with an even exponent and at least one with an odd exponent. It might, or might not, be faster than your approach.